# Want a minimal subgroup, whose orbits cover a submanifold, that is contained in a maximal subgroup which leaves the submanifold invariant

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Say we have a Lie group $G$ acting transitively on smooth manifold $M$ and take a submanifold $S\subseteq M$. It seems to me that there should be some minimal subgroup $G'\subseteq G$ such that $S\subseteq G'x$ for all $x\in S$, as well as some maximal subgroup $G''\subseteq G$ such that $S$ is invariant under the action of $G''$ (i.e., $G''S\subseteq S$). Are there any meaningful conditions we can put on $S$, on $G$, etc., in order to guarantee that such a $G'$ and $G''$ exist such that $G'\subseteq G''$? In other words, when does there exist a subgroup of $G$ which acts transitively on $S$?

If there is some Riemannian structure on $M$, can we say more in the case that $G$ acts by isometries?

If anyone has a good reference for group actions inherited by submanifolds, I would be hugely appreciative! Thank you!

Comment: I can imagine a Zorn's-lemma argument for a minimal $G'$, and an analogous argument for a maximal *abstract* subgroup $G''$, but why should $G''$ be a *Lie* subgroup?  But I guess your question about a subgroup of $G$ that acts transitively makes sense without $G'$ and $G''$.

Comment: @LSpice You're right, offhand there's no reason for $G''$ to be a Lie subgroup, I think.

Comment: @LSpice But of course, this doesn't actually matter if $G'$ is Lie, because then $G'$ is a Lie subgroup acting transitively on $S$ iff $G'\subseteq G''$ for some such *abstract* $G''$ anyway. But yes, transitivity is the meat of the question and doesn't require this construction, it just provides an equivalent condition (unless I've made some mistake).

Comment: @LSpice If $S$ is a closed submanifold of $M$, then any maximal $G''$ will be closed and therefore an embedded Lie subgroup by Cartan's theorem.